# Symfony - catch automatic redirection to login_path

Tags: fosuserbundle, symfony

I need to catch/stop/do own stuff before redirection to the security.yml´s login_path when user is not signed in. Security example:

```
access_control: 
- { path: ^/xy, role: ROLE_USER }
```

I tried to use kernel.request and kernel.controller services but these both actions are triggered after the redirection. I just need to do some own stuff, but every time I go to /xy (not signed), I am instantly redirected to login_path. And I am unable to stop it. We are using FOSUserBundle.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Define an event listener on kernel.request, then check if you are inside the appropriate page (the login page, in your case), then do whatever you want with the response (redirect, create a new response, you name it)

Comment: My problem is, that symfony redirects me automatically to login page. I don't want this. I need to do some stuff before it. Eg. I need to check, if it's ajax request or not. But I am unable to stop redirection.

Comment: Your ajax request should be proctected as well, if they do something relevant. If your only need is to avoid protection on ajax calls, just use URLs that are outside your firewall (to avoid authentication entirely)

Comment: That's the problem. I need to have ajax call inside firewall. But If I use ajax and symfony redirects me during this call to login_page, I don't get the result I wanted. That's why I want to catch automatic redirection when user is not logged in. This is what I am asking. Not another solutions.

Comment: There's something weird, you shouldn't find yourself in a such situation. If your ajax call is inside your firewall, that means that is intended to pass an authentication (and it will work if your user is authenticated). Any action that is *not* meant to be authenticated must be outside firewall

Comment: My action is intended to pass an authentication. That's the problem. FOSUserBundle automatically redirects to login_path when user is not signed in. So in my ajax response I don't have what i want but reponse from login_path. By default, you are signed out after xy minutes (you can't force user to use "Remember me" functionality. And this is the moment, when can be a problem.

Comment: You can listen on kernel.exception. In your listener, define a logic so, for some routes, you do what you want (e.g. not redirecting but throwing an error). Then you can handle errors in javascript (maybe do a redirection from the page where the ajax started to a login page)